# Switch Process in CRM Dynamics with Javascript error

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to switch the selected process from a user's option set selection based on the code below:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("processid").setSubmitMode("always");
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("processid").setValue(workflowId);

Xrm.Page.getAttribute("stageid").setSubmitMode("always");
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("stageid").setValue(processStageId);

Xrm.Page.data.entity.save();
```

However, when this code runs I get the following error:

```
The traversed path should end with the new active stage.
```

I have checked the guids for the processid and stageid and believe they are valid.

Any ideas why this error occurs and the process does not change?

Comment: Can you manually, in the UI, use the switch process button to change to the desired process and then go to the desired stage without entering any data or otherwise altering the record?

Comment: I found the answer. I also needed to set the traversedpath value on the entity which is not mentioned in any of the tutorials I have read because process branching was introduced in 2015.